# Publish all user profiles using Meteor and Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to publish only user profile information, which I'll be using in a member directory. This is what I'm currently doing (autopublish has been removed):

```
// server/publications.js

Meteor.publish("usersListing", function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {profile:1});
});


// routes.js (located in project root)

this.route('users', {
  path: '/users',
  waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe("usersListing");
  },
  data: {
    users: Meteor.users.find({})
  }
});
```

This gives me all user information for all registered users, including services (hashed passwords, etc). I want to limit the data accessible on the client to the profile field only. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close - in the [find](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) options you need to specify that you are limiting the `fields` like this:

```js
Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {profile: 1}});
```

See the [field specifiers documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/sortspecifiers) for more details.